# java does not work for general regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the following code work:

```
String kk = "///hello///";
kk = kk.replace("^(\\/*)", "");
System.out.println(kk);
```

This should take out the '/'s from the beginning.

This regex definitely works:
https://regex101.com/

but it does not work in java. could someone please help me. am i missing something?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll`, since `replace` won't accept regex as argument.

```
kk = kk.replaceFirst("^(\\/*)", "");
```

or

And you don't need to escape forward slashes in java.

```
kk = kk.replaceFirst("^/+", "");
```

Comment: thanks avinash. its saying i can only accept an answer after 11 min. i will definitely accept this as the correct answer. thanks again.

Comment: haha, its a very interesting fish, called pacu, check it out buddy, it will give you a laugh. by the way, any idea if i wanted to also catch the slashes where there could be empty space (of any number and may or may not occur) inside?

Comment: then add capturing group around `/+`, but it's useless here.